# Eclipse autocomplete only working with crl+space

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-cdt

I want to have the auto-complete automatically like in phpstorm.

I have seen the post with said to go "Window >> Preferences >> Java", but i don't have that option in my new install Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers.

I try to go "Window >> Preferences >> General >> Keys" in Command "Content Assist" and change Binding to another keyword but is still not automatically, i still need to use some keyword to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse CDT only supports automatic triggering of auto-complete after certain symbols (., ->, ::).

[Bug 229924](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=229924) is on file for automatic triggering after any character.